# Python Code Coverage Failing with import statements

Tags: python-3.x, code-coverage

I have the following project structure:

```
v/b.py
v/e.py
v/e_test.py
v/p.py
v/__init__.py
```

```
#v/e.py

from b import B
from p import P

class E(object):
   def run(self): pass
```

```
#v/p.py

class P(object):
   def run(self): pass
```

```
#v/b.py

from p import P

class B(object):
   def run(self): pass
```

```
#v/e_test.py

from e import E
import unittest

class ETest(unittest.Testcase):
   def testSomething(self): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then I run this `pip3 install coverage`.

Then `coverage run e_test.py`

It's giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from e import E
  File "~/v/e.py", line 1, in <module>
    from b import B
  File "~/v/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from p import P
ImportError: cannot import name 'P' from 'p' (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/p.py)
```

My question now is how to fix this. Also I want to be able to run:

1. coverage run e_test.py b_test.py files_test.py
2. python3 e_test.py
3. python3 e.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the answer. If I'm in the parent folder which contains the v folder, I can run the following command.

```
PYTHONPATH=./v:$PYTHONPATH coverage run -m unittest discover -s v -p "*_test.py"
```

or without coverage

```
PYTHONPATH=./v:$PYTHONPATH python3 -m unittest discover -s v -p "*_test.py"
```

If I'm inside the v folder, I can run

```
python3 e.py
```

and

```
python3 e_test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

mm, I think P Class is not declared yet,  so you got an error like that

Comment: sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
#v/p.py

class P(object):
   def run(self): pass
```

You haven't defined what P is, the error is reporting that p.py does not have a P object.

Comment: sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: Adding P(object) to p.py should remove that error. Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: I had that already still the same error